Java Spring API NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory
I want to create my first Java API with Spring, so fir start I decided to make a simple API which allow to list all person, one person by id and create one person. I success the compilation but when I run ./mvnw spring-boot:run I have this error :
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.util.BeanDefinitionUtils.<clinit>(BeanDefinitionUtils.java:57) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.EntityManagerBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(EntityManagerBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:325) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:191) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:756) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:572) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409) ~[spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1289) ~[spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527) ~[na:na]
        ... 13 common frames omitted

My project structure :
.
├── mvnw
├── mvnw.cmd
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── example
│   │   │           └── demo
│   │   │               ├── controller
│   │   │               │   └── PersonController.java
│   │   │               ├── DemoApplication.java
│   │   │               ├── model
│   │   │               │   └── Person.java
│   │   │               └── repository
│   │   │                   └── PersonRepository.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── application.properties
│   │       ├── data.sql
│   │       ├── schema.sql
│   │       ├── static
│   │       └── templates
│   └── test
└── target

My PersonController :
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.model.Person;
import com.example.demo.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/persons")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Person getPersonById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return personRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Person createPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }
}

My Person class :
package com.example.demo.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private LocalDate dateNaissance;
    private String numTelephone;
    private String mail;
    
}

My pom.xml :
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.7.18</version>
       <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
       <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
          <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <!--<dependency>
          <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
       </dependency>-->


    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.8.1</version>
             <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I use OpenJDK 11 with Maven and If I've understood correctly, javax has been replaced by jakarta, so I've modified the dependency in my pom.xml, but I don't know why the error still refers to javax.
I tried to replace jakarta.persistence dependency by javax.persistence but It don't compile now so I think it's not de good way.
Someone have any idea to help a Java noob please ?

Remove jakarta.persistence-api, fix the imports to javax.persistence (as you are on an old version of Spring Boot) and re-run. Al the needed dependencies are already part of spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, don't try to be smarter then those dependencies (unless you are very sure what you are doing). Or remove the said dependency and upgrade to Spring Boot 3.3.1 and use JDK17.

Yeah I forgot to replace my import when I tried with javax dependency, In my case I have to stay in Java 11 that's why, thx a lot

Java 17 has nothing to di with JakartaEE. You can happily upgrade to Java17 without the need to move to JakartaEE.

In the new Spring versions «javax.xxx» package imports should be replaces by «jakarta.xxx». However since you are using older Spring boot version (2.7.18), you do not need to change it. You must continue with the «javax.xxx» imports. (or update to the Spring 3.x version).

Worth noting that moving to Spring Boot 3.x also makes it mandatory to upgrade to minimally Java 17.
